# Android ChipDrawable width not fill his parrent

Tags: android, styles, material-components-android, android-chips

I'm trying to use ChipGroup that hold some Chips with text only.
everything works fine. the problem starts when there is short text.
for some reason the text doesn't fill the chip itself, and i can't fix that...
[image]
[image]

I'm using this layout for Chip:

```
<com.daytwo.core.widget.CustomChip         
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/chip"
style="@style/Chip"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minWidth="64dp"/>
```

And my style is:

```
<style name="Chip" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="chipBackgroundColor">@color/background</item>
    <item name="rippleColor">@color/ripple</item>
    <item name="chipStrokeWidth">2dp</item>
    <item name="chipMinHeight">50dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: What does it mean: *doesn't fill the chip itself*?

Comment: you can see at picture. if's seems that drawable chip has padding, so drawable boundary smaller than chip boundary. and than i have ugly space between chips

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `Chip` has a **`chipMinTouchTargetSize`**.This affects both the vertical and horizontal margin of a chip to ensure that it is at least `48x48dp`.

[image]

You can disable it using **`app:ensureMinTouchTargetSize="false"`** in each chip of the `ChipGroup`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I've looked for that attribute for hours!